# ¿Lógica en php o en Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla en Mysql de usuario. Con los siguientes campos de información:

- usuario
- password
- email

Quiero que cuando se registre un usuario, no pase que el nombre de usuario o el mail se repita con algún nombre de usuario o contraseña de los usuarios ya registrados.

Si pongo la propiedad "unique" a los dos campos *(usuario y email)* solo funcionaría cuando **el nombre de usuario Y el email en *simultaneo***, se repiten en mi tabla.

Ejemplo:

```
Si los usuarios registrados en mi tabla son:
nombre:        password:      email:
usuario1       *****          usuario1@ejemplo.com
usuario2       *****          usuario2@ejemplo.com
usuario3       *****          usuario3@ejemplo.com

Si un usuario se registra con la siguiente información, no debería poder:
nombre:        password:      email:
usuario1       *****          carlos@ejemplo.com (usuario1 ya existe en mi tabla)
user4          *****          usuario2@ejemplo.com (usuario2@ejemplo.com ya existe en mi tabla)
```

Por lo tanto quería saber si existe alguna propiedad en mysql para resolver esto, o tengo que hacer la lógica en php.

Comment: En situaciones similares a las que planteas lo he tenido que realizar la comprobación en PHP de que cada elemento que no debe repetirse no exista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que estas creando mal los indices unicos, tienes que poner unico cada columna no la combinación, algo asi:

```
    CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Para esto:

```
INSERT INTO `testing`.`user` (`user`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('usuario1', 'xxxx', 'carlos@ejemplo.com');

INSERT INTO `testing`.`user` (`user`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('user4', 'xxxx', 'usuario2@ejemplo.com');
```

Se genera:

```
[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry 'usuario1' for key 'user'
[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry 'usuario2@ejemplo.com' for key 'email'
```

De todas maneras tienes que atrapar la excepcion pues es critico tener registros duplicados y un dolor en el trasero, te recomendaria manejar ambas cosas.

Has una búsqueda como mencionaron antes de la inserción

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `user` WHERE user = 'usuario1' OR email = 'carlos@ejemplo.com';
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `user` WHERE user = 'user4'    OR email = 'usuario2@ejemplo.com';
```

Tengo entendido que hacerlo con un COUNT es mas rapido, y con OR.

Answer (score 0):

Tendria que hacer del lado de PHP que cuando el usuario este escribiendo se dispare un `Ajax` que consulte si existen coincidencias lo puedes hacer con `JavaScript` con la función `onkeyup` para que vaya buscando o hasta que se salga del input con `onblur`, te recomiendo que sea así porque podrias hacerlo desde MySql pero realmente no sería lo correcto podria generarte problemas.

Comment: Seria bien esa idea, pero hay que tener en cuenta que es mejor no saturar el servidor, podría hacer eso mismo pero al perder el foco, que cuando lostFocus, entonces salga un mensaje como que, usuario ya existe, o el correo.

Comment: Que tal onchange

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un SELECT antes de usar el INSERT

```
$query="SELECT `id` FROM `Users` WHERE  `email` = ".$email." AND `User`=".$user
```

dependiendo la seguridad que manejes quizás deberías pensar en una función como esta:

```
function verify_user($email, $user, $mysqli) {  
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `Users` WHERE  `email` = ? AND `User`=? ")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $user);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows==1){
            return  true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
     }  
}
```

así en tu código puedes llamar a esta función:

```
if(!verify_Email($email, $user, $mysqli);){
         //tu insert va aqui
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, entiendo tu pregunta, lo que haría yo en mi caso, es preguntar primero por el correo, cuando el usuario escriba el correo en el input, y luego pierda el foco el input, si el correo no existe como tal registrado en al base de datos, que salga un mensaje arriba debajo del input como quieras, que sea un mensaje que avise al usuario que puede registrarse con ese correo, de lo contrario pues que el correo ay esta registrado en la base de datos. Lo mismo para el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta corta:**

Usa triggers.

**Respuesta larga:**

Ten siempre en claro cuales son las funciones de las tecnologías que usas. Una base de datos es para almacenar tus datos pero también para mantener su consistencia, por ese motivo es que existen las llaves primarias y foraneas, las restricciones unique, etc. del mismo modo si la lógica es para mantener tu data consistente y sin duplicidad esa lógica debe estar en tu base de datos.

Esta recomendación viene a que si algún día decides reemplazar PHP por otro lenguaje vas a tener que implementar nuevamente la consistencia (si es que te acuerdas de que existía eso al migrar), teniendo esto en la BD, ella misma se encargará de restringir esos casos. Para ello lo más conveniente es usar un trigger que verifique esa restricción antes de los insert/update.